# LINQ group by expression syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a T-SQL query similar to this:

```
SELECT r_id, r_name, count(*)
FROM RoomBindings
GROUP BY r_id, r_name
```

I would like to do the same using LINQ. So far I got here:

```
var rooms = from roomBinding in DALManager.Context.RoomBindings
                        group roomBinding by roomBinding.R_ID into g
                        select new { ID = g.Key };
```

How can I extract the count(*) and r_name part?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rooms = from roomBinding in DALManager.Context.RoomBindings
                        group roomBinding by new 
                        { 
                           Id = roomBinding.R_ID, 
                           Name = roomBinding.r_name
                        }
                        into g
                        select new 
                        { 
                           Id = g.Key.Id,
                           Name = g.Key.Name,
                           Count = g.Count()  
                        };
```

**Edit by Nick - Added method chain syntax for comparison**

```
var rooms = roomBinding.GroupBy(g => new { Id = g.R_ID, Name = g.r_name })
                       .Select(g => new
                           {
                               Id = g.Key.Id,
                               Name = g.Key.Name,
                               Count = g.Count()
                           });
```

Comment: any ideas how a would be a "Having Count" in the query syntax side?

Comment: @RollRoll - a "Having Count" can be accomplished by adding another `Where` expression to the end of the chain in the answer.  For example: `.Where(x => x.Count > 1)`