# How to populate my class object with linq to EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

my class,

```
  public class User
    {
        public string Username
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string [] Roles
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

my query is,

```
var innerJoinQuery =
                            (from u
                            in db.Users
                            join ur in db.UserRoles
                                on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
                            join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
                            select new {
                                Username=u.Username,
                                Password=u.Password,
                                RoleName = r.RoleName 
                            }).ToList();
```

data it is getting in above query is like,

```
username   password  RoleName
john        123       user
john        123       admin
john        123       super user
David       12345     super user
petter      123456    user
```

I want to get this data in my userclass object using Linq,

it should be like,

```
username   password  RoleName
john        123       { "user", "admin", "super user" }
David       12345     { "super user" }
petter      123456    { "user"}
```

I already tried many examples from net i did not get my answer.

hopes for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the following which uses a sub-query to select all of the role names:

```
var innerJoinQuery = (
    from u in db.Users
    select new User
    {
        Username = u.Username,
        Password = u.Password,
        Roles = (from ur in db.UserRoles
                 join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
                 where ur.UserID == u.UserID
                 select r.RoleName).ToArray()
    }
).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can use `group...by...into`:

```
var innerJoinQuery = (
    from u in db.Users
    join ur in db.UserRoles on u.UserID equals ur.UserID 
    join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
    group r by u into g
    select new User
    {
        Username = g.Key.Username,
        Password = g.Key.Password,
        Roles = g.Select(c => c.RoleName).ToArray()
    }
).ToList();
```

Assuming your ORM supports this, it *may* generate a better query versus aggregating the keys and then sub-selecting from the aggregated groups.

If the ORM cannot translate `ToArray`/`ToList` (which Linq-To-SQL can't), you can either

1. change the type of `User.Roles` to be `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `string[]` and then remove the `ToArray` calls above, or
2. select into an anonymous type *first*, materialize the query (`ToList`) and then re-project the results into your `User` type

`#2` looks like the following:

```
var innerJoinQuery = (
    from u in db.Users
    select new
    {
        u.Username,
        u.Password,
        Roles = (from ur in db.UserRoles
                 join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
                 where ur.UserID == u.UserID
                 select r.RoleName)
    }
).ToList();

var users = innerJoinQuery.Select(c => new User { 
     UserName = c.UserName, 
     Password = c.Password,
     Roles = c.Roles.ToArray() 
});
```

Or with the `group...by` variant:

```
var innerJoinQuery= (
    from u in db.Users
    join ur in db.UserRoles on u.UserID equals ur.UserID 
    join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
    group r by u into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.Username,
        g.Key.Password,
        Roles = g.Select(c => c.RoleName)
    }
).ToList();

var users = innerJoinQuery.Select(c => new User { 
     UserName = c.UserName, 
     Password = c.Password,
     Roles = c.Roles.ToArray() 
});
```

Note that all of these solutions have the upside that they perform the grouping and/or sub-querying *at the database*, whereas the other answer does it *in-memory*

Comment: getting this error (LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] ToArray[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) method. Not sure if your ORM supports it but you can always group after making query to db:

```
var innerJoinQuery =  (....)
    .ToList()
    .GroupBy(u => u.Username)
    .Select(g => new User
    {
      Username=g.Key,
      Password=g.Select(i => i.Password).First(),// can be moved to grouping clause
      Roles = g.Select(i => i.RoleName).ToArray() 
    })      
    .ToList();
```

To try to perform group by in your query to db you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796165/linq-group-by-expression-syntax) question for example.

Comment: i tried it is giving error (The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.)

Comment: @Doc sorry, copypasted to little, added `.ToList()` after you query, try again.

Comment: its working now can i move the result of this query to my class "User" object

Comment: @Doc see update. Just change last select to  from `new {..` to `new User` and change `RoleNames` part part of it.

Comment: i understand your query i got it i mean to ask, i have object like (private List<Models.User> UserList = new List<Models.User>();) How i add 'innerJoinQuery ' result in "UserList" ? for example i can add in UserList like (UserList.Add(new Models.User { Username = "Admin", Password = "12345", Roles = new string[] { "Admin", "Super User", "User" } });)    I am using UserList variable other places.

Comment: `UserList.AddRange(...)` ?

Comment: This is performing the grouping on the C# side and *not* on the database side (because of the `ToList` before the `GroupBy`. That means it's doing it all in-memory. @Doc you should consider if that is what you want -- because this can all be achieved on the database side (see my updated answer)